# Accessing Local Directory via UNC Prompts for Credentials

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, administrative-privileges

We have a Windows 2016 server with the hostname, `foo.example.com`.

When logged into it as a Domain Admin, if we enter itself as a UNC path in Windows Explorer...

```
\\foo.example.com\d$
```

...we can access it.

Same if we use `localhost` or it's IP.

However, if we use another DNS A record for the same IP, let's say `bar.example.com`, we get prompted for Administrative credentials.

AND if we enter correct credentials, we get a **The specified network password is not correct.**

What are we doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: Something else I should've mentioned is that this issue only occurs when on the server itself. If I navigate to the alternate A record (NOTE: not a CNAME...if that matters) across the network, it works fine.

Comment: This sounds like a Strict Name Checking issue - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3181029/smb-file-server-share-access-is-unsuccessful-through-dns-cname-alias

Comment: @joeqwerty that appears to be specific to CNAMEs. This is an A record, and I just added an update that the alternate A record works fine across the network - it's only when attempting to access it on the server itself that it throws this error. That said, does what you post still apply you think, or does that potentially change things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using kerberos authentication, adding another DNS record pointed to a file server will not work.  The correct why to add another name is the following command:

NETDOM COMPUTERNAME foo /ADD bar.example.com

IPCONFIG /registerdns